# Java Api Callbacks crashes on dotnet framework version 4.5 and above

Tags: java, c#, java-access-bridge

trying to work with Java Access Bridge in c#, everything works fine however whenever i try to subscribe on dotnet framework version 4.5 and above e.g.

```
JabApi.MouseClickedDelegate mcd = new  JabApi.MouseClickedDelegate(HandleMouseClickedDelegate);
JabApi.setMouseClickedFP(mcd);
```

Application crashes, but same code works fine on dotnet framework version 4.0.
Checked Event log : Faulting module name: windowsaccessbridge-64.dll